# `Html.select` displaying wrong value when changing the options

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, elm

I have a `Model` with `options` and a `selected` item.

```
type alias Model =
    { options : List String
    , selected : String
    }
```

The `Model`'s initial value is given by `Model ["aaa","bbb"] ""`
To generate the options I use the following helper: **[This ended up being the problem, see correct version below]**

```
selectHelper : (String -> msg) -> Bool -> List String -> String -> Html msg
selectHelper oninput enabled options current =
    select [ onInput oninput, disabled <| not enabled ]
        (Utils.distinct identity options
            |> List.map
                (\opt -> option [ value opt, selected <| opt == current ] [ text opt ])
        )
```

and my view and update are simply:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ selectHelper Select True (model.selected :: model.options) model.selected
        , text model.selected
        ]

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Select newval ->
            ( { model | selected = newval }, Cmd.none )
```

When loading the page, I see the select control with `""` selected as the default options.
Now I open the dropdown and click on the `"aaa"` option.
In the `Model`, I see that `selected` is now `"aaa"`. However, visually, on the html page, I see that `"bbb"` is selected.

Does anybody know about this?
What is the correct way to add the current value as an ad-hoc option which can disappear if deselected?

EDIT (2023.06.30):
This is the implementation of my `Utils.distinct` function which the `selectHelper` uses:

```
distinct : (a -> comparable) -> List a -> List a
distinct extractKey set =
    set
        |> List.map (\a -> ( extractKey a, a ))
        |> Dict.fromList
        |> Dict.values
```

EDIT (2023.07.09)
The correct version of `selectHelper` which works is:

```
selectHelper : (String -> msg) -> Bool -> List String -> String -> Html msg
selectHelper oninput enabled options current =
    Keyed.node "select"
        [ onInput oninput, disabled <| not enabled, value current ]
        (distinct identity options
            |> List.map
                (\opt -> ( opt, option [ value opt, selected <| opt == current ] [ text opt ] ))
        )
```

Comment: This seems to work as expected to me: https://ellie-app.com/ncWCRKPBxYda1

Comment: Not sure it directly relates to your problem, but when we had desync problems on `select` controls, setting `Html.Attributes.value` on the `select` element helped to resolve them.

Comment: @glennsl Your implementation skips the `distinct` part, which would delete the first entry. I'll have to think if duplicating the first item is okay for me, but I'm still curious about what causes this issue.

Comment: @RobertK.Bell tried to add a `value` attribute to the `select` itself, nothing changed.

Comment: The only reason why you need `distinct` is because you're adding the selected item as an option. What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: I ended up redesigning the system around this constraint.   
The issue was with two different clients: one was aware of all the legal options of the select and one that could send arbitrary strings. I wanted to use the the select as an easy way to see what the value set in the other client was but to be able to change it to only legal values... (not sure if I managed to get the idea through).

In any case, at this points this is more interesting to me as an academic question more than anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing are artefacts of the elm virtual dom handler getting out of sync with the Dom itself.

If you want dynamically to add/remove items to a select element while it is being used, you will need to use https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Keyed - give each `option` a unique `key`.

Comment: I've changed the line to be `(\opt -> Keyed.node "option" [ value opt, selected <| opt == current ] [ ( opt, text opt ) ])` but the behavior is unchanged. Is there anything else I'm missing? does the parent `select` needs to be `Keyed` as well?

Comment: yes, it is the select that uss Keyed and each option has a tag